# Missing Assembly References

Tags: unity, assets

I am trying *to develop a heatmap that reveals bots exploration on a basic 2d map*. I will then use *pathfinding* for the bots to go to an area of the map where the bots have hardly visited that part of the map. I've downloaded a package from CodeMonkey "unitycodemonkey.com" which consists of a heatmap. It tracks the mouse's movements on the grid and in each cell, it has a value of how long the mouse has been in it for while the colour changes indicating how hot the cell is.

I downloaded another package from the website. This package consists of bots and I will use place them on this heatmap to track their movement however I get **error messages** that **Entities does not exist in the namespace 'Unity'**. It asks if I am missing an assembly reference. I tried to use assembly definition reference on the files and scripts however I can only do it for **Mathematics** and **can't do it for the rest of the error messages** as it doesn't give me the option to. Please can you help me in solving this issue?

Code:

```
/* 
    ------------------- Code Monkey -------------------

    Thank you for downloading this package
    I hope you find it useful in your projects
    If you have any questions let me know
    Cheers!

               unitycodemonkey.com
    --------------------------------------------------
 */

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Entities;

public struct LevelComponent : IComponentData {

    public float level;

}
```

[image: The error message I received]

Comment: Please include your code in your question. It's not really easy to tell the problem without seeing the code but my guess is you are writing `Entities...` and Unity searches for it in the `Unity` namespace and returns an error because there is no `Entities` in `Unity`. instead, you should use `name.Entities...` and the `name` depends on the package you use

Comment: I've added the code that the syntax error is referring to. I've used Unity.Entities however the error says that it doesn't exist. Do you know what package Entities belong in?

Comment: Does the package you use have any kind of documentation? For example, I am using an A* pathfinding package which I can access by `using pathfinding` and it was noted in the documentation. Also, you can just ask on their site!